# How to get rows that are inserted or updated today, without timestamp column

Tags: mysql

My tables doesn't have any timestamp column then in that case how do we get the rows that are inserted today. Table has primarykey with auto increment and rest of all the columns are of INT datatype.

Answer (score 1):

No way. You need to have specified field for this.

You are not able to get this without an extra field.

Comment: Do we need to add extra datetime filed?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you can not check the rows for special day.